# how to read a specific row from csv file using CsvReader in java

Tags: java, csv

I am using CsvReader library and want to read a specific row from a csv file  in java. 
Sample csv :

```
**Name**,     **Address**,        **Email-Id**
student,    studentaddress,     student@email.com 
student2,   student2address,    student2@email.com 
employee,   employeeaddres1,    employee@email.com
```

I want to read the row where name is 'student2'.
Could you please provide a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

As rows have different sizes in bytes, and as the CSV format doesn't contain an index, you can't have a [random access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) directly to one row.

So you must read all precedent rows and simply skip them until you're at the desired one.

Answer (score 2):

I have some experience with this type of operation ,
just try this API  http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

we have an option to skip the first `n` records

eg: `CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"), '\t', '\'', 2);`

this shows it will skip the first 2 records.
look through it

[Other API's](http://commons.apache.org/csv/)

Comment: opencsv isn't an Apache project - you're probably confusing it with [commons csv](http://commons.apache.org/csv/)